# Subtract a month from a date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to get the first day of last month from any date.
I know that I can use `monthdelta(datetime(2010,3,30), -1)` to get last month, but it doesn't return the first day.

Comment: Why not `datetime(2010, 3 - 1, 1)`?

Comment: Because I have a lot of date `2016-05-13 19:05:38, 2016-06-18 19:05:46, 2016-06-12 19:06:46, 2016-03-13 19:07:04, 2016-02-13 19:09:59, 2016-09-13 19:11:11 ` and to all date I want to get  first day of last month

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by first calculating the first day of current month ( or any given date ), then subtracting it with datetime.timedelta(days=1) which gives you the last day of previous month.

For demonstration, here is a sample code:

```
import datetime

def get_lastday(current):
    _first_day = current.replace(day=1)
    prev_month_lastday = _first_day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return prev_month_lastday.replace(day=1)
```

Comment: down voted as the current answer gives you the *last* day of last month, not the *first*

Comment: @donkopotamus Thanks for pointing out, I did a mistake. I edited the post.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this. With using `datetime` and `datetutil`.

(if `datetutil` not available for you install `pip install python-dateutil`)

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime
In [2]: import dateutil.relativedelta
In [3]: today_date = datetime.now().date()
In [4]: today_date
Out[1]: datetime.date(2016, 7, 5)
In [5]: last_month = today_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
In [6]: last_mont_first_date = last_month.replace(day=1)
In [7]: last_mont_first_date
Out[2]: datetime.date(2016, 6, 1)
```

**Input:**

```
datetime.date(2016, 7, 5)
```

**Output**

```
datetime.date(2016, 6, 1)
```

Comment: I try `df['used_at'] > (dates[i] - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1))).replace(day=1)` but it return `TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'day'`

Comment: Before that I try `df['used_at'] > dates[i].replace(month=date.month - 1, day=1)`  but it return only one day

Comment: I think you are trying a different things.

Comment: `df['used_at']  > (dates[i] - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=1)` try this working for me.

Comment: I write about it earlier, it return `TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'day'`

Comment: Check the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html . It'a a valid argument.

Comment: it returns only day, when `buy=1`

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
from datetime import date
d = date.today()
d.replace(
    year=d.year if d.month > 1 else d.year - 1,
    month=d.month - 1 if d.month > 1 else 12,
    day=1
)
```

Comment: Does this work if the current month is january?

Comment: i try `df['used_at'] > dates[i].replace(month=date.month - 1, day=1)` but in return only 1 day

Comment: So what about year ?

Comment: Yeah, good point ;)

Comment: Note that the year issue was fixed. After 3 years I wasn't sure if I had done it or not.